# Eucalyptus, some euwatch commands are not working

Tags: eucalyptus

which service in eucalyptus provides euwatch commands ?
I created cloudWatch for my scaling group, but it keep its state (INSUFFICIENT DATA) as it is, after evaluation period...how to automate it's working?

Answer (score 0):

The eucalyptus-cloud service on the [cloud controller](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#install-guide/euca_components.html) currently (3.X) provides both the AutoScaling and CloudWatch services.

[Eucalobo](http://testingclouds.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/getting-started-with-eucalobo/) is a useful tool for checking the available CloudWatch data, but without more information (which version are you using, what commands are being run, etc) is is hard to suggest a specific solution to the issue.